# DataType to store characters of length 10000 in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sqldatatypes

DataType to store characters of length 10000 in SQL Server 2008 , I tried using VARCHAR(MAX) , also nVARCHAR(MAX) none are of help.
I am declaring one output variable in dynamicSP, which I want to be of size greater than 10k characters.

Thanks!

Comment: varchar(max) and nvarchar(max) hold up to 2 GB of data. This should easily accommodate 10000 (or even 10 million) characters. What do you mean when you say it's of no help?

Comment: You can use also data type text.

Comment: @αNerd: ***NO***, do ***NOT*** use `ntext` (or `text`) anymore! `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: @mark_s You are right. But I am surprised that they  have not dropped it yet. After all, It's a talking point for many years now. That is why the notification says "a future version", not "the future version"

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem. Our solution is store the query in a variable as a text. then concatenate them until the query ended.

Example:

```
DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(MAX) 

SET @sql = 'query here' 

@sql=@sql+'query here' 

exec(@sql)
```

Comment: DECLARE "@sql" AS NVARCHAR(MAX) --> If you observe, again we are limiting the variable value to nvarchar(MAX) which contains 4k character will not solve our problem even if we concatenate.Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @PKernel `NVARCHAR(MAX)` is not limited to 4Kb